# Phonegap Error object from try/catch is missing information

Tags: cordova, error-handling

With the following code in chrome

```
try {
   throw new Error( "Error!" );
} catch(e) {
   console.log(e.name);
   console.log(e.message);
   console.log(e.stack);
}
```

I get something like the following in console

```
Error: Error!
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (file:///sample/platforms/ios/www/js/app.js:58:22)
at HTMLButtonElement.f.event.dispatch (file://sample/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery.min.js:3:4816)
at HTMLButtonElement.h.handle.i (file://sample/platforms/ios/www/js/jquery.min.js:3:716)
```

However, when I build with PhoneGap I get something like this

```
@file://Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/29A502DF-F664-434A-94C6-12AAA20BCF33/HelloWorld.app/www/js/app.js:53
dispatch@file:///Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/29A502DF-F664-434A-94C6-12AAA20BCF33/HelloWorld.app/www/js/jquery.min.js:3
i@file:///Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/29A502DF-F664-434A-94C6-12AAA20BCF33/HelloWorld.app/www/js/jquery.min.js:3
```

I'm wondering whether its possible for me to get the first stacktrace or if PhoneGap just screws up exception messages. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I was using v8 (chrome's javascript engine) while testing in browser and phonegap uses the native engine (webkit)